# create subdomain address of subdomain that does not exist, to redirect to the main domain

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

Would it be possible to set a 301 redirect for

sub.domain.com to redirect to domain.com/directory

even when the subdomain does not exist.

Comment: where do you set the existing subdomains?

Comment: I do not have any existing subdomains, I was wondering if I could mask a subdomain, using htaccess. What I mean is, create a fake subdomain, that only is a redirect to another webpage

Comment: yes, you can do it with rewrite rules in an htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub1|sub2)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

This will redirect sub1.domain.com to www.domain.com/sub1. Replace domain.com with your address, and enumerate the subdomains you want to redirect using | as separator